# how to make minimum table row 3 in angular *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ngfor

i am trying to add minimum rows. Even if the list of groups are less than 3 it should add empty rows .

```
  <ng-template ngFor let-au [ngForOf]="GROUP_AU_LIST" let-i="index" >
    <tr>
      <td>  <p-checkbox name="auname" [value]="au.auId" [(ngModel)]="au.checked"></p-checkbox>      </td>
      <td>{{au.auShortName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <ng-template *ngIf="i<3">
      <tr *ngFor="let dummy of ' '.repeat(rem).split(''), let x = index">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>

  </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I'd just take the lazy way out and make 3 empty `<tr>`s, each with an `*ngIf` that checked the length of `GROUP_AU_LIST`.

```HTML
<ng-template>
  <tr *ngFor="let au of GROUP_AU_LIST">
    <td><p-checkbox name="au.name" [value]="au.auId" [(ngModel)]="au.checked"></p-checkbox></td>
    <td>{{au.auShortName}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="GROUP_AU_LIST.length < 3"><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr *ngIf="GROUP_AU_LIST.length < 2"><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr *ngIf="GROUP_AU_LIST.length < 1"><td></td><td></td></tr>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may push empty objects or empty string based on the type of array that you have until you get `length=3`

```
public GROUP_AU_LIST = ['one'];
constructor() {
    while(this.GROUP_AU_LIST.length < 3){
       this.GROUP_AU_LIST.push('');
    }
}
```

html

```
<table> 
   <tr *ngFor="let au of GROUP_AU_LIST; let x = index">
        <td>{{au}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider adding a pipe to the array that appends empty objects to the list when count is less than 3 ?
You can then use a single *ngFor and guarantee there are atleast 3 rows.

Comment: yea sure, can you please give any particular example?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#flyingheroespipe
Try reading this example. In the custom pipe you create, check the length of the input array and push as many empty objects as you would want.

Comment: If he pushed empty objects to his array, his *ngFor would attempt to access their properties which would output `undefined` in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table in the typescript file and initialize it with 3 of any values u want: `rows[]=[1,2,3]`.

After, make a loop in the `tr` tag of `table`: `<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">`

That will surely display at least 3 rows in your table.

Comment: but i need to add them dynamically, it can be 3, or 2 or 1, based on existing data

Comment: but u said minimum 3, so this will be initialization. after u could make them dynamically using functions